# Clear one input if other input has no value

Tags: javascript, forms, input, calculator

I'm trying to create a simple conversion calculator with two inputs (Celsius and Fahrenheit).  I want to adjust the script so that **if one input is cleared, it will clear the other input** too. Here is a screenshot of what happens at the moment.

[Image of two inputs for conversion calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvpZP.jpg)

I've tried a number of if statements to check if one or the other is null or "", and if so then set value to null, but that doesn't work.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

and the **HTML** is:

```
<input type="text" id="cVal" placeholder="celsius" onkeyup="convert('C')">
<input type="text" id="fVal" placeholder="fahrenheit" onkeyup="convert('F')">
```

and **Javascript**:

```
function convert(degree) {
    var celsius = document.getElementById("cVal").value;
    var fahrenheit  = document.getElementById("fVal").value;

    if (degree == "C") {
        if (celsius === null || "") {
            fahrenheit = null;
        }
        else {
            var calcFah = celsius * 9/5 + 32;
            document.getElementById("fVal").value = Math.round(calcFah);
        }

    }
    else {
        if (fahrenheit === null || "") {
            celsius = null;
        }

        else {
            var calcCel = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9;
            document.getElementById("cVal").value = Math.round(calcCel);
        }
    }
}
```

If you prefer, here is my **Codepen url**: http://codepen.io/coetzercreative/pen/WxXBEK

Comment: "I've tried a number of if statements to check if one or the other is null or "", and if so then set value to null, but that doesn't work." - Can you adjust your codesample to include these unsuccessful attempts?

Comment: sure...I'll adjust and edit post shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if `celsius` or `farenheit` are numbers. So you converter may look like this.

```
function convert(degree) {
  var celsius = document.getElementById("cVal");//.value;
  var fahrenheit  = document.getElementById("fVal");//.value;

  if (degree == "C") {
    if (celsius.value == '' || Number(celsius.value) == Math.NaN) {
    //note that Number('') == 0
      fahrenheit.value = "";
      return;
    } 

        var calcFah = celsius.value * 9/5 + 32;
        fahrenheit.value = Math.round(calcFah);
  }
  else {
    if (fahrenheit.value == '' || Number(fahrenheit.value) == Math.NaN) {
      celsius.value = "";
      return;
    }

    var calcCel = (fahrenheit.value - 32) * 5/9;
    celsius.value = Math.round(calcCel);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I like the fact that you're also checking if it's not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should work like this:

```
function convert(degree) {
  var celsius = document.getElementById("cVal").value;
  var fahrenheit  = document.getElementById("fVal").value;

  if (degree == "C") {
    if (!celsius) {
      document.getElementById("fVal").value = "";
      return;
    } 

        var calcFah = celsius * 9/5 + 32;
        document.getElementById("fVal").value = Math.round(calcFah);
  }
  else {
    if (!fahrenheit) {
      document.getElementById("cVal").value = "";
      return;
    }

    var calcCel = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9;
    document.getElementById("cVal").value = Math.round(calcCel);
  }
}
```

If the calculation is for celsius, then it checks if it is an empty value by doing:
`if (!celsius) { ... }`

When a value is empty or undefined, this evaluates to false. The same is repeated with fahrenheit.

You could also just add all of the checking at the beginning, clear all fields, and return to get out:

```
function convert(degree) {
  var celsius = document.getElementById("cVal").value;
  var fahrenheit  = document.getElementById("fVal").value;

  if ((degree === "C" && !celsius) || (degree === "F" && !fahrenheit)) {
      document.getElementById("cVal").value = "";
      document.getElementById("fVal").value = "";
      return;
  }

  if (degree == "C") {  
        var calcFah = celsius * 9/5 + 32;
        document.getElementById("fVal").value = Math.round(calcFah);
  }
  else {   
    var calcCel = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9;
    document.getElementById("cVal").value = Math.round(calcCel);
  }
}
```

```js
function convert(degree) {
  var celsius = document.getElementById("cVal").value;
  var fahrenheit  = document.getElementById("fVal").value;
  
  if ((degree === "C" && !celsius) || (degree === "F" && !fahrenheit)) {
      document.getElementById("cVal").value = "";
      document.getElementById("fVal").value = "";
      return;
  }
  
  if (degree == "C") {  
  var calcFah = celsius * 9/5 + 32;
  document.getElementById("fVal").value = Math.round(calcFah);
  }
  else {   
    var calcCel = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9;
    document.getElementById("cVal").value = Math.round(calcCel);
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.calcWrap {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 960px;
 height: 100px;
}

.degCont{
 display: inline-block;
 background: #f5f5f5;
 padding: 15px 30px;
 width: 43%
}

input {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 12px 18px;
 font-family: 'Helvetica-neue', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="calcWrap">
            <div class="degCont">
                <input type="text" id="cVal" placeholder="celsius" onkeyup="convert('C')">
            </div>

            <div class="degCont">
                <input type="text" id="fVal" placeholder="fahrenheit" onkeyup="convert('F')">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation making it easy to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with jQuery (it is easier) but also in JavaScript if you prefer. What you need to do is 
1) determine whether the value is `"undefined"` 
2) if value is undefined, empty the other input value

```
if($(element1).attr("value") == "undefined"){
   $(element2).attr("value", "")
}
```

Comment: thanks. Yes I prefer Javascript for now since I'm new to it.

Comment: Ok, so in your code instead of putting `null`, you should put `undefined` and to set the value for the other element, specify it as two quotes ("")